# How to Debug "Linq to SQL" Source

Tags: linq-to-sql, debugging

In accordance with the steps from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx), 
I can debug .net framework source code,But I can not debug step in Linq to SQL code,anyone help me!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source code for linq to SQL obviusly has Not ben released yet, however you can take a lokk at System.Data.Linq with "Reflector". [link](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)
There is also a Visual Studio Debugger Plugin to visualize lambda expressions As Sql(have a google)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the source symbols for Linq2SQL assemblies have not yet been released on the symbol servers.

Hopefully at some point they will.